# How to write group by and having in a relational algebra interpreter?

Tags: group-by, query, relational-theory, relational-algebra

I am practising writing relational algebra (RA) expressions in [RA interpreter from Duke](https://users.cs.duke.edu/~junyang/ra2/), but I can't figure out how to represent **group by** or **having** (from SQL). I have this expression, but I need to group it by `countries`, and get only those that have `count>5` (I can work around count with another query, but I don't know how to group):

```
\project_{country, count(*)}(locationTable);
```

Also, is there **order by** in RA?